Do I need to replace my whole gear shifting box or is there a way to just change the shifting handle?
My ex boyfriend took off with my car keys and threw the keys into the woods somewhere . When I came to his house I noticed it looks like he kicked the shifting gear or did something to it to damage it . I dont have my keys to turn the car on to see if I can even move the gears or not . But from the looks of it does the whole assembly maybe have to be replaced or just the knob itself ?
￼


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like your EX is a real winner. Sorry for your pain. What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

It’s a 2008 Saturn aura XR

Looks like the trim is broken, chances are mechanically it is still okay. Looks like this could also be posted on https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ :D

I'd suggest you won't really know about the shifter until you get a new set of keys for it and get it started. Like EᑎOT stated, it will probably work as is.
